# Why should a rule be standardized in Backward Chaining before looking for substitutions?

Tags: algorithm, logic, artificial-intelligence

I understood most of the **Backward Chaining** algorithm (for first-order logic), but not what `Standardize-Variables(rule)` is for. Below is the pseudo-code of the algorithm:

```
function FOL-BC-Ask(KB, query) returns a generator of substitutions
    return FOL-BC-Or(KB, query, {})

function FOL-BC-Or(KB, goal, θ) returns a substitution
    for each rule in Fetch-Rules-For-Goal(KB, goal) do
        (lhs ⇒ rhs) ← Standardize-Variables(rule)
        for each θ' in FOL-BC-And(KB, lhs, Unify(rhs, goal, θ)) do
            yield θ'

function FOL-BC-And(KB, goals, θ) returns a substitution
    if θ = failure then return
    else if Length(goals) = 0 then yield θ
    else
        first, rest ← First(goals), Rest(goals)
        for each θ' in FOL-BC-Or(KB, Subst(θ, first), θ) do
            for each θ'' in FOL-BC-And(KB, rest, θ') do
                yield θ''
```

I'm studying on the book [Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) and the code comes from there. The book simply says

> FOL-BC-Or works by fetching all clauses that might unify with the goal, **standardizing the variables in the clause to be brand-new variables**, and then ...

I do understand this, but I do not understand *why* it needs to be done, or what would happen without it.

I hope someone can explain this. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, my memory of this material is pretty dim, but IIRC you won't get the most general unifier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for standardizing variables apart is rather mundane: scope. A variable is "local" to its clause, so when it appears in multiple clauses, it really should be treated as a different variable in each clause. Standardizing apart makes sure this is made clear by using different names in each clause.

Let me explain in more detail. In a normalized first-order logic theory, each clause is implicitly universally quantified. If I have a theory with two clauses

happy(X)

happy(X) or not friends(X,Y),

it means the same as

for all X: happy(X)

for all X : for all Y : happy(X) or not friends(X,Y)

You can think of "for all X" as a sort of "declaration" of X (in the programming sense of "declaration"), so each of these variables is, so to speak, "local" to the clause, in the same sense that a local variable in programming is local to its scope. It is pure coincidence that X is used in both clauses, and in fact we can rename them at will within each clause and obtain perfectly equivalent theories such as

for all U: happy(U)

for all V : for all W : happy(V) or not friends(V,W)

or even

for all X: happy(X)

for all Y : for all X : happy(Y) or not friends(Y,X)

Standardizing apart comes into play because if we try to unify these two clauses, there will be two variables with the the same name X even though they do not necessarily refer to the same entities. If we try to unify the two clauses above without standardizing apart first, we will unify X and Y and end up with

happy(X) or not friends(X,X)

which implies that both arguments of "friends" are the same even though that would *not* be implied if we simply renamed the variables. Unifying the same perfectly equivalent two clauses using U, V, W names results in

happy(U) or not friends(U, W)

where now the two arguments of "friends" are not required to be the same.

The fact that we obtained different results from unifying perfectly equivalent theories shows us that something must be incorrect. And indeed what is incorrect here is unifying two clauses that use a variable with the same name (X) even though they are not really the same variable and could be equivalently renamed to something else.

David Einsentat's comment is correct that failing to standardize apart is incorrect as it does not provide the most general unifier, because it may provide an unifier that has spurious constraints such as the equality we saw above, preventing it from being as general as it should.

Standardizing apart solves this problem by renaming the variables to "brand-new ones", meaning variables that do no appear anywhere else and which therefore do not pose the risk of colliding in this way and introducing a false equality based on purely arbitrary name choices.